# align on the right the entry in a listview

Tags: android, listview, alignment

I have a listview to show messages in a chat. I'd like to show the received messages on the left and the sent messages on the right.
Please consider that it is not enough to align the contained views because I need to show a background of the entry and the background should be aligned too. SO the whole entry should be aligned.

Is there a way to do it?

I tried to use `android:layout_gravity="right"` but it did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try setting the parameter programatically in your adapter using `LayoutParams`.

Something like the following for sent messages:

```
LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.MyLinearLayout);
// need to cast to LinearLayout.LayoutParams to access the gravity field
LayoutParams params = (LayoutParams)ll.getLayoutParams(); 
params.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT;
ll.setLayoutParams(params);
```

and the reverse (change RIGHT to LEFT) for received messages.

Comment: it is important to add that you should set the gravity for a framelayout within the main layout. I used a slightly different method

Comment: Glad I could point you in the right direction.  Thanks for posting your final solution, it's good to know.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to do it by using:

```
    LayoutParams params = (LayoutParams) frame.getLayoutParams();
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT, alignRight?0:1);
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT,  alignRight?1:0);
    frame.setLayoutParams(params);
```

what it is important is that I had to add a frame within a RelativeLayout for my entry, because params.addRule is available only for RelativeLayout. If you try to do the same with the view passed to bindView you get a different LayoutParam that does not support addRule

Answer (score 0):

Of course!
you need an Adapter. In the adapter, when you inflate the ListItem, just inflate different Items for sent and received messages!

Comment: OK is this the only method? I didn't want to use it because I have several views in the entry and I do not want to replicate all of them: one for the left and one for the right

Comment: I don't understand the problem then. You don't have to replicate them. You have to create 2 xml (ListItems), one for received messages, aligned right, and one for sent messages, aligned left. When a new item is inserted to the list, the adapter inflates one or another item and sets the text!